# How can I use bash filedescriptors with git am?

Tags: git, bash, github

This may be a bit esoteric but it has confused me.

`git am` is a nifty tool to apply a mbox. Much like `git apply` applies a patch file `git am` will apply a series of patch files. A key difference in their usage is that `git am` requires a file to work with while git apply is happy taking a stream. For example:

```
git apply /path/to/foo   # Works
git apply < /path/to/foo # Works
git am /path/to/foo      # Works
git am < /path/to/foo    # Does not work
```

Since GitHub will output patch files if you append the `.patch` to a commit it only makes sense that `curl` should be used with these.

I can apply a patch but loose the commit metadata:

```
curl -L https://github.com/user/repo/commit/bada55.patch | git apply
# Or better
git apply <(curl -L https://github.com/user/repo/commit/bada55.patch)
```

But in contrast I want the metadata so I'd prefer using `git am`. The problem is that `git am` oddly doesn't work the same. Piping does work:

```
curl -L https://github.com/user/repo/commit/bada55.patch | git am -
```

I rather use the file descriptor like so:

```
git am <(curl -L https://github.com/user/repo/commit/bada55.patch)
```

However this results in the following error:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   612    0   612    0     0   1624      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1627
error: cannot read mbox /dev/fd/63
error: cannot split patches from /dev/fd/63
fatal: Failed to split patches.
```

Why doesn't the above work. I thought the `<(…)` syntax took the output of the command and placed it in a fifo which is as if it was saved to a file.
 What is happening under the hood here?

Comment: The `cmd2 <(cmd1)` construct uses a pipe rather than a fifo (though the difference should be irrelevant).  Essentially, instead of `cmd1 | cmd2` it's `cmd1 |`, then "move pipe to fd 63", then `cmd2 /dev/fd/63` to make cmd2 read from fd 63.  Given that piping works, it's odd that the bash construct doesn't.  Git does use libc `getdelim` in place of its own code if configured to do so, but that seems like it should still work.

Comment: Is this a bug? Should it be reported to the Git devs?

Comment: Probably, but I'd try to pin it down more before reporting.  At the least you'd need to note which version(s) of git it fails for, and how they were configured at compile time, on what platform, etc.